# Add node to Front of Linked List then count number of nodes in Linked List

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I would like to add a node to the front of the list by calling an object and print the length of the list. So far I keep getting a segmentation fault. I want something basic enough that I can build ideas from:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node {
  public:
    int data;
    Node *next; //creating a pointer to store the address of the next node or null (at the end of a linked list)
   int key;

    Node(int d){
        data = d;
        next = NULL;
        key = -1;
    }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node *head;
    LinkedList (){
        head = NULL;

    }

    void addNodetoFront(int data){
        Node *n = new Node(data);//allocate memory on the heap with address that is returned to n (pointer)


        n->next=head;
        head=n;


        if(n != NULL){
            n->key = n->next->key+1;
        }
        else{
            n->key = 1;
        }
    }

};

int main(){
    LinkedList linkedlist;

    linkedlist.addNodetoFront(2);
    linkedlist.addNodetoFront(3);
    linkedlist.addNodetoFront(4);
    linkedlist.addNodetoFront(5);
    linkedlist.addNodetoFront(26);
    linkedlist.addNodetoFront(27);
    linkedlist.addNodetoFront(9);
    linkedlist.addNodetoFront(45);
    linkedlist.addNodetoFront(87);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected is linked list of 9 nodes, and the program prints 9 elements.

Comment: Think of what `addToFront` does when you add the first element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `head` starts off as NULL.  When you add the first node, then that node becomes the head, and its `next` pointer becomes NULL.  Now, look at this:

```
if(n != NULL){
    n->key = n->next->key+1;  // But n->next is NULL :(
}
```

Above, `n->next->key` is undefined behavior, as you are dereferencing a NULL pointer.  Furthermore, while it's actually impossible for `n` to be NULL, the following logic for if `n` *hypothetically* could be NULL is crazy:

```
else{
    n->key = 1;  // But you said n was NULL :(
}
```

The only way any of this makes sense is if you actually had a typo in your test and you meant:

```
if(n->next != NULL)
```

Putting this all together, makes your function look like this:

```
void addNodetoFront(int data)
{
    Node *n = new Node(data);

    n->next = head;
    head = n;

    if (n->next != NULL) {
        n->key = n->next->key + 1;
    } else {
        n->key = 1;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the following more compact style achieves exactly the same:

```
void addNodetoFront(int data)
{
    Node *n = new Node(data);
    n->next = head;
    n->key = (head ? head->key + 1 : 1);
    head = n;
}
```

Comment: If there is but a single node in the linked list, then head would point to null. But if a new node is created, then the head should be set to the new node, then of course I think if you did that you would lose the linked list

Comment: _"if you did that you would lose the linked list"_ ... if you did what?  `head` is the first element of the list.  When you replace `head` with `n`, you had already set `n->next = head`, which preserves the entire list such that it follows the new node.  Your crash has nothing to do with the list containing items.  It is entirely related to when the list is empty and you try to add something.

Comment: So when I am calling the objects in main, the list is not being created?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You are creating a list.  In your original question, you experienced a crash when attempting this.  I answered to show you where you went wrong.  Now I'm confused by your responses.  Have you made the fix that I recommended?

Comment: Are you saying by changing the conditional that would be the fix?

Comment: Yes.  Let me edit my answer and spell it out a little more clearly.

Comment: Thank you. I haven’t quite been able to grasp this topic quite yet.

Comment: No problem.  You'll get the hang of it.  When in doubt, remember there's nothing special about a pointer.  You can think of it as a phone number.  Do what you like with the phone number, write it down in multiple places or whatever, but it accesses a phone somewhere.  When you lose all copies of the number, you can't call it anymore.  And if you own it, you can tell the phone company to terminate its contract and disconnect the number at any time even if there are copies floating around.  Okay, maybe the analogy is getting weird now.

Comment: My whole journey to understanding most of these concepts has been through analogies/pictures because of how abstract these concepts can be. (Thumbs up)